# How to have Darcula UI and Light Theme on Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

On my Windows desktop this is not a problem, but on Intellij for my Macbook, when I have the Solarized Light theme active and switch to Darcula UI (I want it dark), the entire color scheme changes to Darcula. I would like to keep it to where the UI is Darcula and the color scheme light or dark, not automatically changed upon changing the UI. I have looked at all the options and can't seem to figure this one out.
I do not have any pictures, and this is my first SO post, so I apologize if it is not asked correctly.

Comment: Please check [this forum thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000190310-Stuck-with-a-theme), it should help with your problem.

Comment: Great! Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 2):

First change the IDE theme, then change the editor color scheme, you should see the following dialog:

[image: change IntelliJ IDEA theme]

Say **No**, and you will keep the original IDE theme after changing the editor scheme.

In case you don't see this dialog, close IntelliJ IDEA, find [`idea.config.path`](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`/options/options.xml` file and remove the following line:

```
<property name="change.laf.on.editor.theme.change" value="true" />
```

More details can be found in [this forum thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000190310-Stuck-with-a-theme).